# Replace php extension with slash / using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite php extensions with `.htaccess`. I want to replace php extension with slash `/` . For example If I have: `http://example.com/about-us.php` will be `http://example.com/about-us/`

How can I make this modifying this piece of code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

Thanks to all!!!

Comment: have you seen my update ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What URL is shown in browser when you get 404? Are these the only rule or you have more?

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Apache 2.2 and Apache 1.3.7

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

You can do it with one line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

Apache 2.2

for `http://www.domain.com/services.php`

and get it with

`http://www.domain.com/services` OR `http://www.domain.com/services/`

Apache 1.3.7

if you want

`http://www.domain.com/services/`

you need `..//$`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)//$ /$1.php [L]
```

**Update**

http.conf

> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

possible false options : must have **MultiViews**

DocumentRoot

```
<Directory "G:\Programme\Apache Group\Apache\htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: With your suggestions, Is this now the full source: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)//$ /$1.php [L]   ?

Comment: @Hawk : 
you need to choose only one possibility. `RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / ` with `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]` OR `RewriteRule ^(.*)//$ /$1.php [L]` !

Answer (score 0):

In html head, include:

```
<base href="http://www.yourdomain.com/">
```

In htacces:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[^.]+$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

It's worked to me. Good luck!