# Add slash end of the URL after remove .php from file using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to add slash end of the url after remove .php from file.
For ex. www.xyz.com/abc/

I have used below .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php**strong text**
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548556/replace-php-extension-with-slash-using-htaccess

Comment: @DavinderKumar not a dupplicate, as it's the rule before which makes this less-straightforward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: use `$1.php/` in your rule.

Comment: I assume `**strong text**` is just a _typo_?!

Answer (score 1):

You might want this

```
RewriteEngine On
# where the .htaccess file is located (public path from document_root)
RewriteBase /subdir/path/based/on/document_root


# does not apply to existing directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# rewrite dir-like urls to php script and  END rewriting to avoid infinite loop
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1.php [END]

# apply to existing files only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# browser redirect to canonical URL
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```